# How do you get the child that was updated in a firebase .on?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_instance_and_path) on the firebase realtime database, it says:

> If you set the path for your function as /foo/bar, it matches events at both of these locations: /foo/bar and /foo/bar/baz/really/deep/path.

I'm trying to use an event listener, that fires every time anything inside a ref on the database is changed. The problem is, I only have the ref to the parent of the child that was updated, and every time the .on is fired, the snapshot given lists all of the children, and not just the one that was updated.

My database is structured like so:

```
/profiles/$uid/userId
/profiles/$uid/ownedProducts/$product
```

I want to put a listener on the ownedProducts or the $uid object, which I am unable to do as there are lots of data that are dynamically changed. Therefore, I placed a .on listener to /profiles, which fires every time a user is updated but it doesn't provide the child that was updated.

Would there be a way to get the child that was updated? I can think of a few workarounds but they would use a lot of storage.

For reference, I am using node.js with the firebase admin SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from my friends off-platform, I have solved the problem:

I used another database to store transactions, which I put a .on listener on.

Now I was able to just loop through that database and give them the product! A simple and easy workaround, which you can use with .on("value", () => {}).